# Error in rowSums(Qf) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions (msm::msm2surv)

Tags: r, syntax-error, survival-analysis

I am using function msm2surv in msm package and trying to convert longitudinal data to the format flexsurve package likes. Following is my sample called tmp.

```
tmp <- structure(list(id = c(89, 90, 90, 91, 91, 91, 92, 92, 93, 93, 
94, 94, 94, 95, 95, 96), days = c(9157, 0, 9156, 0, 8394, 9156, 
0, 9156, 0, 8079, 0, 8933, 9003, 0, 8430, 0), event = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "id", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0L, 1:2, 3:5, 6:7, 8:9, 10:12, 13:14, 15L), group_sizes = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 3L, labels = structure(list(
    id = c(89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame", vars = "id", drop = TRUE, .Names = "id"), .Names = c("id", 
"days", "event"))
```

running codes:

```
library(msm)
Q <- matrix(c( 
  0,1,1,1,1,0, 
  0,0,1,1,1,1, 
  0,0,0,1,1,1, 
  0,0,0,0,1,1, 
  0,0,0,0,0,0, 
  0,0,0,0,0,0
), nrow=6, ncol=6, 
byrow=TRUE, 
dimnames=list(from=1:6,to=1:6)) 

dat <- msm2Surv(data=tmp, subject="id", time="days", state="event", Q=Q)
```

It gives me the error: Error in rowSums(Qf) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions.

I checked the dimension of the dataframe, it sounds ok to me. But the error is there. Does everyone know how to resolve the problem/error?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the `tbl_df` to `data.frame` and it should work

```
out <- msm2Surv(data=as.data.frame(tmp), subject="id",
               time="days", state="event", Q=Q)
dim(out)
#[1] 31  8
```

The "tmp" dataset is a grouped tbl_df and has lots of attributes.  By converting to `data.frame`, we remove those attributes.